Flutter 3.24.5 Web App Crashes on Firefox After Frequent Actions: Memory Leaks or Resource Overload?
I am encountering a persistent issue with my Flutter web app built using Flutter 3.24.5, where the app crashes in Firefox after performing frequent actions such as navigating between pages, submitting forms, or fetching data from an API. This causes the browser to close the tab and display the error message: "Your tab just crashed."
Note: The issue seems specific to Firefox, as the app works correctly in other browsers, such as Chrome and Safari, without crashes or significant warnings.
Warnings in the Console
targetWidth and targetHeight for multi-frame images not supported
Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded, this may cause a flash of unstyled content.

I suspect the issue might be related to memory leaks, resource overconsumption, or compatibility with Firefox.
Steps to Reproduce

Use Flutter 3.24.5 to build a web app.
Deploy the app with Firebase integration.
Perform frequent actions such as:
Navigating between pages.
Fetching data or submitting forms.
Rendering multi-frame images (e.g., GIFs).
Observe the crash behavior in Firefox after some time.


Sample Code List
class DummyListDesktop extends StatelessWidget {
const DummyListDesktop({super.key});
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GetBuilder<DummyPageController>(builder: (controller) {
            int length = controller.filteredList.length;
            return RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: (() => controller.getDummyList()),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: length > 0 || controller.loading
                        ? ListView.separated(
                            itemCount:
                                controller.loading ? AppStyles.shimmerLength : length,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppStyles.mainPaddingOrMargin),
                            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const DividerWidget(
                                  height: 0,
                                  thickness: 1,
                                ),
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Container(
                                  decoration: UIHelper.defaultShadowDecoration(
                                    onlyTopRounded: index == 0,
                                    borderRadius: index == 0 || (index == length - 1)
                                        ? AppStyles.globalRadius
                                        : 0,
                                    onlyBottomRounded: (index == length - 1),
                                  ),
                                  child: InkWellCustomWidget(
                                    onlyTopRounded: index == 0,
                                    borderRadius: index == 0 || (index == length - 1)
                                        ? AppStyles.globalRadius
                                        : 0,
                                    onlyBottomRounded: (index == length - 1),
                                    padding: AppStyles.mainPaddingOrMargin,
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
                                    onTap: controller.loading
                                        ? null
                                        : () => controller.itemTap(index),
                                    child: controller.loading
                                        ? _shimmerWidget()
                                        : _dataWidget(
                                            index: index,
                                            data: controller.filteredList[index]),
                                  ));
                            })
                        : controller.errorWidget(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        );
      }
    }


I hope you don't mind me asking; can you show us your code? I suspect that there is a mishandling of the data while other simultaneous processes are being handled as well.

@DevQt sample add now check

Thank you for that. I am familiar with the issue of Layout was forced before the page is fully loaded. I apologize if I can't provide an example since I can't reproduce the issue on my machine. So, I will provide my understanding of the issue to help you. There is a conflict between the layout and the data that is being processed; for example, if the layout is not yet prepared without the complete data, then it will behave unexpectedly, including if there is another process that is not handled correctly and runs simultaneously. You have to find out where it is specifically.

@DevQt this is warnings because of these app should not crash

It depends, I guess...
